# Parent as link but not child

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have been searching for an answer to this, but cant seem to find one. So now i go to the genius' of this site ;-)

Lets say i have a parent (div A) and a child (div B) and I want to have div A as a link - then of course the link would work if i click inside div A - also if i hit div B.

How do i stop this from happening? Div A should be a link but if i click on the child element inside nothing should happen.

```
<div A>
<div B></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you make div behave like a link? Javascript? Then share your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resort to JavaScript for this. Bind an event handler to B and prevent the default behaviour of the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>a { display: block; }</style>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://example.com">
    <div id="a">Hello
      <div id="b">World
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', function (e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
    });  
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @steffenhenriksen If this worked out for you please accept this as the answer to reward Quentin for his contribution

Answer (score 1):

Just return false

```
<a href="google.com">Parent Link
    <div id="b" onclick='return false;'>Child Not a link</div>
</a>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKu6e/)